# Is it acceptable to add multiple full paths with sys.path.append or is there a Pythonic way to approach this?

Tags: python

I have a Python script Foo() that imports Bar() in the same folder.

The Python script Foo() is called from a different location when in a Docker container vs the test/build pipeline.

So for now I added:

```
sys.path.append('/project_name/a/b')
sys.path.append('/builds/project_name/a/b')
import bar
```

Is this acceptable or more of a hack/smell?
Is there a better approach without rewriting the call to Foo()?

Edit: This is in CentOS7

Comment: Edited the question and removed the Linux tag. I'm looking for a solution for a Linux environment and not Windows.

Comment: It's a hack. Your installer should be installing things to a standard location, rather than your script hard-coding a non-standard location. Docker containers, virtual environment, etc have pretty much eliminated the need for this kind of run-time search path modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to have a standard location but if that is not allowed for whatever reason then the following code can be used to only have one sys path append.

```
from pathlib import Path
current_path = Path().cwd()
common_path = (current_path.resolve().parent.parent).joinpath('a/b')  # Go up two dir then to a/b

import sys
sys.path.append(common_path.as_posix())
import bar
```

The nice thing about the standard solution is that you can:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/a/b/"
```

So then it's possible to edit ~/.bashrc then run source ~/.bashrc if desired.

To append the export to the bashrc from some bootstrap file you can do:

```
echo 'export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/my/modules/"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec bash
```

source ~/.bashrc won't work where the terminal instance changes